# Scrolling Text without white background (Corona SDK)

Tags: coronasdk

I'm creating an interactive book for tablets with Corona SDK.

The design has a full screen image, with scrolling text overlaid to one side.

I started using widget.newScrollview but it seems very restricted. So far it seems you have to have a white background, which is kinda killing the aesthetic.

Anybody know a work around for the background, or an alternate way to deal with the large amount of scrolling text?

I was thinking about making it a series of images, but I've concerns with memory and the quality of the font when scaled up for iPad 3 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local scrollView = widget.newScrollView{
        top = myTop, left = myLeft,
        width = someWidth, height = someHeight,
        bgColor = { 255, 255, 255, 210 },   --set the RGBA background color.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Speeder. 

I was using an older version of the widget. In the latest version, not only can you change the background colour with bgColor, but you can also hide the background with hideBackground, which would also solve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

you have to set hideBackground = true when you create it

```
local list = widget.newScrollview{

hideBackground = true,

}
```